# Why I can't change date format in PHP

Tags: php

I'm facing problem with date format in PHP because I can't change time format
I want to get this format 2015-12-07 13:46:58 am

This is timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Phnom_Penh");
date_default_timezone_get();
```

To echo times out

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s a");
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s a");
```

Result

2015-12-07 **1:46:58** am

2015-12-07 **1:46:58** am

They are the same and

Comment: `13:46:58 am` isn't a valid time..... hrs `00`-`11` are `am`, `12`-`23` and pm; you can't have `13am`

Comment: Oy my god I'm confusing now Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I think now is day time not night time haha

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Format letter `H` or `G` is conflicting with `a`.

`H` is for a 24 hours clock, which isn't applicable to am/pm suffix

`G` is for a 12 hours clock, but it's `13:46` which is actually `1:46 am`

Bottom line: the `a` rules.